# Firefox Browser Security - White List sites

Tags: firefox

Wondering the best way of approaching a particular problem.

An enterprise deployment of around 300k User access devices uses Internet Explorer as the "Corporate Browser".

There is a defined use-case where a limited rollout of Firefox is to be made to support a particular application.

We need to be able to whitelist a number of URL's so that only they can be accessed from the Firefox Browser.

How easy is this?

Comment: Why don't you just implement code on the server side to notify people to use Firefox.  Your unlikely to find it easy to make Firefox be able to access those websites in a whitelist.

Comment: Its more complicated than that... due to the environment being worked in fine grained control over application behaviour is required, and just notifiying users to use FF isn't the problem.

Comment: The issue is only allowing users of Firefox to go to certain locations. i.e. Implement a lockdown